# How to redirect stderr of python3 script using tee pipe?

Tags: bash, terminal, stderr, tee, python3

I am a Debian and RedHat user. I would like to redirect stderr (module `logging`) from a `Python3` script. The script outputs a lot of things and the part I want to capture can be fetched using:

```
python3 ./script.py --input ./*.txt --verbose 2>> ./script.log
```

This appends stderr to `./script.log`. But I would keep this dialog also in terminal. Usually I achieve this by *piping* the `tee` command. The problem is, the following `shell` line (executed from a `bash` file):

```
pyhton3 ./script.py --input ./*.txt --verbose | tee -a ./script.log
```

Does output into the terminal but does not output anything to `./script.log`.
Any idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display *both* stdout and stderr on the terminal while *only* capturing stderr to file, use:

```
python3 ./script.py --input ./*.txt --verbose 2>&1 1>/dev/tty | tee -a script.log
```

The way that the shell handles redirections is quite subtle.  Here, the `2>&1` results in the command's stderr being piped to the `tee` command.  `1>/dev/tty` results in the command's stdout going directly to terminal.  Order is important.  If the order of these redirections is reversed, nothing would go to the pipe. Alternatively, if `1>/dev/tty` were omitted, then both stdout and stderr would be piped to the `tee` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect your stderr (2) to stdout (1) and then pipe it to tee like that

`python3 ./script.py --input ./*.txt --verbose 2>&1 | tee -a ./script.log`